# How Do I Get Selenium JavascriptExecuter For Anaconda?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, spyder, anaconda3

I am coding a web scraper and I want to scroll down but when I try using this

`jse.executeScript("scroll(0, 250);");`

`jse` is an `error` how do I get `JavascriptExecuter` I am currently using Anaconda Spyder I will switch to get `JavaScriptExecuter` though.

Answer (score 1):

```
executeScript
```

is invalid in python, it should be `execute_script`

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, Y)")
```

Y in vertical scrolling val. for 250 you can try :

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 250)")  #to scroll down
```